# Adding extra button to FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we modify or change the view of **[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)** as per our need ?

I want to add an extra button to it and write the event on it. Please Suggest me for the same asap.. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can do whatever you want but the question is: what do you want to do?

Comment: As i mention i want to add the extra button called as workweek clicking on which only weekdays(mon-fir) must be selected.i am not getting how to do that?

Comment: there is a whole section in API regarding header and buttons.. review it and provide specifics as they relate to the API  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/header/